insertAdjacentElement only renders on page refresh
I'm developing a chrome extension. Problem arises when I attempt to insertAdjacentElement. I can see that the css style is added to the page head but not the element itself until I refresh the page. I've tried checking the document load completion state and adding setTimeouts. Not sure how to go about it.

export const config: PlasmoCSConfig = {
  matches: ["https://www.linkedin.com/*"],
  all_frames: true
}

let lastUrl = location.href
new MutationObserver(() => {
  const url = location.href
  if (url !== lastUrl) {
    lastUrl = url
    onUrlChange()
  }
}).observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true })

function onUrlChange() {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    console.log("URL changed!", location.href)
    GhostOverview()
  }
}

function AddContainer() {
  const style_element = document.createElement("style")
  style_element.innerHTML = `
      .sample-container {
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);  
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      } 
      .title-header {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px; 
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    `
  document.head.appendChild(style_element)

  const document_div = document.getElementsByClassName("t-14")[0]
  if (document_div) {
    const testDiv = document.createElement("div")
    testDiv.className = "ghost-container"
    testDiv.innerHTML = '<h2 class="ghost-header">Header</h2>'
    document_div.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", testDiv)
    
  }
}


export default function GhostOverview() {
  if (window.location.toString().includes("linkedin.com/jobs/search/")) {

    
    AddContainer()
...



Replace lastUrl check with document.querySelector(".t-14")

@woxxom Like this? Same issue occurs.
new MutationObserver(() => {   if (document.querySelector(".t-14")) {     onUrlChange();   } }).observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });

This element may be already present when the script runs, so try also calling GhostOverview() at the end of the script.

@woxxom that happens to crash the content script if I add GhostOverview to the end.

Well then debug it in devtools by setting breakpoints and stepping through the code via F10/F11.
